# check if an object supports the buffer protocol python

Tags: python

I am looking for the Python equivalent of the Python C-API PyObject_CheckBuffer.

I.e. I would like to check if an object supports the buffer protocol, but from Python.

Answer (score 14):

I think you're just supposed to use the standard try-it-and-see-if-it-works technique:

```
# New-style buffer API, for Python 2.7 and 3.x.
# PyObject_CheckBuffer uses the new-style API.
# 2.6 also has the new-style API, but no memoryview,
# so you can't use it or check compatibility from Python code.
try:
    memoryview(thing)
except TypeError:
    # Doesn't support it!

# Old-style API. Doesn't exist in 3.x.
# Not quite equivalent to PyObject_CheckBuffer.
try:
    buffer(thing)
except TypeError:
    # Doesn't support it!
```

Comment: NameError: name 'buffer' is not defined

Comment: @HristoVenev You must be using Python 3, in which case you should use the keyword `memoryview` instead of `buffer`. The recommended safe version is to check sys.version_info at the top near your import statements. If it is greater than (3,), then define `buffer = memoryview`, then you can use `buffer` in Python 2 or 3.

Comment: @ely: Or without version sniffing: `try: from builtins import memoryview as buffer; except ImportError: pass`

Comment: @ely: It's not a blanket `except` - it says `except ImportError`.

Comment: @ely: From a different perspective, an explicit check for the feature you want to use is more clear and explicit than a check for versions that have that feature.

Comment: @ely: Checking for a version doesn't explain why you need the version. It also avoids bugs where you accidentally check for the wrong version.

Comment: @ely: It's not about laziness or writing less code. It's about checking what you actually need. It's like structural vs nominal typing - we care about whether an object has a `do_thing` method instead of whether it implements `IThingDoer`. Version checks are like `isinstance` checks.

Comment: If you ever want to see a case where the balance is heavily in favor of feature checks, take a look at Javascript. Feature checks are heavily encouraged over browser version checks, because feature support across browsers and browser versions is a huge mess.

Answer (score 3):

Working with short data snippets on performance-critical code, I had to try out different approaches. Depending on your application, one might be better than the others.

```py
def ensure_bytes__try(data):
    try:
        # memoryview used only for testing type; 'with' releases the view instantly
        with memoryview(data):
            return data
    except TypeError:
        return data.encode()

def ensure_bytes__isinstance(data):
    # Explicitly test for some bytes-like types
    # - misses array.array, numpy.array and all other types not listed here
    return data if isinstance(data, (bytes, bytearray, memoryview)) else data.encode()

def ensure_bytes__hasattr(data):
    # Works as long as your bytes-like doesn't have 'encode'
    return data.encode() if hasattr(data, "encode") else data

def ensure_bytes__args(data=None, data_bytes=None):
    # Avoid autodetection by using explicit arguments
    return data_bytes if data is None else data.encode()
```

The following benchmark shows time used by each implementation on Python 3.7.4:

```
ensure_bytes__try(b"foo")             ▒▒▒▒█████████████████ 438 ns
ensure_bytes__try("foo")              ▒▒▒▒▒██████████████████████████████████ 797 ns
ensure_bytes__isinstance(b"foo")      ▒▒▒▒█████████ 277 ns
ensure_bytes__isinstance("foo")       ▒▒▒▒▒███████████████████ 489 ns
ensure_bytes__hasattr(b"foo")         ▒▒▒▒████ 171 ns
ensure_bytes__hasattr("foo")          ▒▒▒▒▒█████████ 287 ns
ensure_bytes__args(data_bytes=b"foo") ▒▒▒▒██ 121 ns
ensure_bytes__args(data="foo")        ▒▒▒▒▒█████ 216 ns
```

Shorter bar means faster. The light-shaded part of each bar represents the reference time benchmarked on `ref_bytes(b"foo")` (84 ns) and `ref_str("foo")` (100 ns):

```py
def ref_bytes(data): return data
def ref_str(data): return data.encode()
```

Comment: `memoryview` has no attribute "encode", so `hasattr` won't work the same as `isinstance`, for example.  you could check `hasattr(data, "tobytes")`

Comment: All four functions will return a `memoryview` object as-is, which is intended. My naming is slightly misleading because the functions try to ensure buffer protocol (i.e. bytes-like) return values rather than precisely `bytes`.

Comment: `ensure_bytes__args` seems really weird. If you already know whether your object is bytes-like and you don't need to detect it, then you just *wouldn't call* this function. It doesn't offer anything over just directly handling your object the specific way you already know the object needs to be handled - which is to say, not doing anything if it's already bytes-like, and calling `encode` directly if you know it's something you need to call an `encode` method on to get bytes.