# How to test for bytes-like object?

Tags: python

Which test can tell if an object is a [bytes-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytes-like-object)?

Usually either a string or a bytes-like object can appear in certain function calls. A simple, but indirect solution in such context would be `if not isinstance(obj, str)`.

I've found  [ByteString](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.ByteString) in `collections.abc`. It seems to give the right answers, but I'm not sure if this is the right way:

```
>>> import collections.abc as cabc
>>> isinstance(bytes(),cabc.ByteString)
True
>>> isinstance(bytearray(),cabc.ByteString)
True
>>> isinstance("string",cabc.ByteString)
False
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/30018151/489590

Comment: Why do you want to test the type of an object? In Python, any object that fulfills the interface needed would work, whether or not it's a subclass of `ByteString`.

Comment: @martineau I want to parse the output of `socket.getpeername` for AF_UNIX. _"... programs intended to run on Linux may need to deal with both types of address"_. Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket-families

Comment: @BrianCain Thank you. That is very similar question and answered. Maybe an equivalent for practical purposes (bytes-like = has buffer protocol and C-contiguous buffer). I have no idea what is the latter.

Comment: @martineau: one reason may be because you want an API that accepts either a single object, or a list of them (or, in general, iterable); given that all bytes-like objects are iterable, you need to be able to differentiate between the two

Answer (score -1):

This is almost the right way as `collections.abc.ByteString`, as well as `typing.ByteString`, represents the types `bytes`, `bytearray`, and `memoryview`, but not `array.array`, so you'd need another check:

```
def IsBytesLike(obj):
    return isinstance(obj, typing.ByteString) or isinstance(obj, array.array)
```

Comment: I would accept this answer, but I have to admit, I'm unable to judge if adding `array.array` makes the test complete.

Comment: @VPfB, the [link](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytes-like-object) you provided has the definition of a bytes-like object, including the standard Python types the definition applies to. So, while you can't really test the "C-contiguousness" of a buffer, you can test for whether an object is of a standard type that is definitely bytes-like.

Comment: That link also mentiones "many common memoryview objects". I tried `IsBytesLike` on `memoryview(b'')` and it returned `False`. If you really can't test the "C-contiguousness", than the answer linked by Brian Cain in his comment is probably the best possible.